# Apache2/Nextcloud Docker error: "\OC\Memcache\APCu not available for local cache"

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, cache, cloud, nextcloud

I have an Apache2 Docker container and in `/var/www/html/nextcloud` a mounted path, with the Nextcloud files in it. However, when I try to run the cronjob (`/var/www/html/nextcloud/cron.php`) of Nextcloud with this command:

```
docker exec -u www-data webserver php /var/www/html/nextcloud/cron.php
```

I always get the error:

```
OCP\HintException: [0]: Memcache \OC\Memcache\APCu not available for local cache (Is the matching PHP module installed and enabled?)
```

And yes, it is enabled.

**Apache virtualhost config:**

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName cloud.domain.de
   Redirect / https://cloud.domain.de/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nextcloud"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.domain.de/cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.domain.de/privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.domain.de/chain.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

and with that the cloud runs fine; only the cronjob is not running.

The **Nextcloud config:**

```php
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/nextcloud/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/nextcloud/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'instanceid' => 'oc0lur3krx8v',
  'passwordsalt' => 'dZemkG1vxBvlOJWKbM2qfby4+zQnHf',
  'secret' => '7kv+ZkKR7CLhFckepPJCpxI4eWZWO9EOEW3qzgpg8TIhLsE9',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'IP:99',
    1 => 'cloud.domain.de',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/nextcloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '23.0.0.10',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://IP',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'IP',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbpassword' => '9*oh5VM7h2yHj-(Q',
  'installed' => true,
  'default_phone_region' => 'DE',
  'updater.secret' => '$2y$10$YZw2sSl8ssbt1SOokyC9kOAtui2gmabmhKCmeVzlBTU1rGqVRisFm',
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'maintenance' => false,
  'app_install_overwrite' => 
  array (
    0 => 'occweb',
  ),
);
```

I have memcached now already up down the container made new and written in the Config forever around but it all brings nothing finds anyone the error?

**INFO:**

`IP` is a placeholder for the IP address of the server.

`domain.de` is a placeholder for the domain name
because I do not want to publish the domain (not mandatory).

Comment: [This GitHub thread may be of interest.](https://github.com/nextcloud/vm/issues/2039)

Comment: @Anaksunaman I have already tried this in all possible files but the error remains. I have also compared the configs with the official Nextcloud Docker image as it is built there. And I have transferred this to my container unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `apc.enable_cli=1` in `/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/apcu.ini` or equivalent path depending on PHP or OS setup.

Some users experienced the same issue and fixed it by applying the above change:
https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/27781#issuecomment-873515055

Also, as stated in the Nextcloud Admin Manual (Nextcloud configuration -> Memory caching -> APCu), the APCu is disabled by default on CLI:
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/caching_configuration.html#id1

> APCu is disabled by default on CLI which could cause issues with
> nextcloud’s cron jobs. Please make sure you set the `apc.enable_cli`
> to `1` on your `php.ini` config file or append `--define apc.enable_cli=1` to the cron job call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152074)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Improved the answer, as suggested.